# How to call a function when we click on desktop notfication using python plyer library?

Tags: python-3.x

**Here is my sample code using python plyer library:**

```
from plyer import notification

    notification.notify(title = "Sample  notification1" ,message = "You have successfully signedoff",app_icon = None,timeout = 5,toast = True)
    
    notification.notify(title = 'Sample  notification2' ,message = 'whatsapp',app_icon = None,timeout = 5,toast = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can this function:

```
from plyer import notification
if __name__=="__main__":
     notification.notify(title = "Sample  notification1" ,message = "You have successfully signedoff",app_icon = None,timeout = 5,toast = True)
     notification.notify(title = 'Sample  notification2' ,message = 'whatsapp',app_icon = None,timeout = 5,toast = True)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped alot to me, Appreciated.